# Where can I find ui.core and ui.tabs js files?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I can't seem to find these files anymore, not even on google cdn or jQuery's pages. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download)?

Comment: http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/01/jquery-ui-1-8-17/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI by default is going to come with all widgets code included but you can customize and download from

http://jqueryui.com/download

In your case, You need to just deselect all non-core package and select tabs only from widget and click Download.